# Make text of invite links to XING and LinkedIn different

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization, careers-germany

Both hyperlinks on [StackOverflow Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/)  in German that invite contacts from XING or LinkedIn display the text "Kontakte auswählen...".

To make it clearer where each hyperlink points to (without hovering the mouse over the links), the text should include the name of the social network.

Better names for the hyperlinks would be "XING-Kontakte auswählen..." and "LinkedIn-Kontakte auswählen...".

Also since we are on a German site, should the title be named "Einladen von XING & LinkedIn"

> [image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI has been updated so that the distinction between the XING and LinkedIn links is apparent. Also, the title now uses the translated version.

Here is the updated version. Thank you for your report!

> [image: updated invitation section]